# Using Non-Linear Mixed Models instead of Sqrt-transformed Dependent Variable in Linear Mixed Model

Tags: lme4, mixed-models, nlme

I am running a Random Coefficient Mixed Model in `R` using `lme` in `{lme4}`. I had to transform my dependent variable by square-root because of problems of uniqual variance of the errors. However, with this formulation of the DV, the interpretation of my coefficients' predictors becames quite tricky.

1. Fitting a Non-Linear Mixed Model with `nlme` of the homonimous package in `R` would be a solution?
2. Can someone help setting up the code for my case? I do not really
   get the meaning and the use of the argument `start =`.

Comment: There is not much information here to base solid advice on. I would only want to mention that fitting a variance structure with the weights parameter could be an alternative to the tranformation.

Comment: Could you give more information on how to proceed using the `lme` package?
Given that I know that the heteroskedasticity comes from the non linear relation among DV and covariates and that DV_sqrt better describe this relation, how should I set the `weights =` option?
In a nutshell which function should I use in `weights = varFunc()`?

Comment: Sorry, I really don't want to go into more details without a lot more information. Possibly you even should use a GLMM. Do you have a non-linear model from the scientific background and know something about the expected error structure? I think your question might be better suited for stats.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I have tried fitting my model with `glme` using a gamma distribution, but the error structure does not improve.
I have been able to identify part of the source of heteroskedasticity by including a specif variable in the random part of the equation, however the non-normal distribution of my DV translate in non-normal errors which cause heteroskedasticity.
Transforming the DV with sqrt the qqnorm plot shows that the transformed-DV follow exactly a normal distribution.
However, as already said interpretation of coeff.s is quite tricky.